# How to access object defined in parent, from child Slider movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, parent, movieclip

Here is my app structure:

> parent->[slider->[movieClip1,movieClip2,movieClip3]]

So I basically have a few movieclips inside a Slider component.
Now I have an object defined in the parent time line

```
var myObj:Object = new Object();...
```

I want to access this object from movieClip1 in the Slider component.
I've tried:

```
trace(MovieClip(this.parent).myObj.A_function_in_the_object());
```

Which outputs:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   fl.controls::BaseButton@222082e1 to flash.display.MovieClip.  at
>   SliderTrack_skin/frame1()

And

```
trace(parent.myObj.A_function_in_the_object());
```

Which outputs:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property myObj through a reference
>   with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

How do I access the object that's defined in the parent timeline from a child movieclip?

Answer (score 1):

Because the structure of flash components are complex, this.parent doesn't always return the class that you expected. So, if you want to access parent object, you should use while loop instead of "this.parent.parent.parent ... ".

Like this.

```
var obj: Object = this;
while (obj.parent != null) {

    obj = obj.parent;

    // If "obj" is the class you expected, stop loop.
    if (obj is MovieClip) {

        // Do something like below.
        MovieClip(obj).myObj.A_function_in_the_object();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MovieClip(this.parent)` is `slider` not the `parent`. You can access the parent timeline by `MovieClip(this.parent.parent)`. If you want to access the `myObj` then `MovieClip(this.parent.parent).myObj` also you can access any of the property in the `myObj` by `MovieClip(this.parent.parent).myObj.propertyA`. In this case `A_function_in_the_object` is the property of `myObj`.

Comment: May I know the frame of the `myObj` and `movieClip1` have defined?